# How to apply scrollbar to windows mobile application using c#.net, windowsce, .net3.5 framework, windows mobile 6 professional

Tags: c#, windows, mobile

How to apply scrollbar to windows mobile application using .net compact framework, and windows mobile 6 professional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure control's AutoScroll property is set to `true`. When the content does not fit, the scroll bars appear automatically.

Comment: thanks for responding,but my problem is if my device is  in landscape mode it fits properly according to screen size .iam having dynamic keypad below r bottem to my application,but when i view the same application in portiade mode i would like to keep the dynamic keyboard constant at bottom  and apply scrollbar to rest of my application.to do this what i have to do ?